# How to make a textbox case insensitive

Tags: c#, foreach, case-insensitive

Yes, I realize that there are many things on this, but they aren't working for me.

```
        if (textBox1 != null)
        {
            string text = textBox1.Text;
            foreach (string s in apple)
            {
                if (s.Contains(text))
                {
                    listBox1.Items.Add(s);
                }
            }
        }
```

In the listbox, I have: "Bob" and "Joe". The textbox searches for names but if I put in "joe", then it doesn't show joe's name, however, if I put "Joe", it shows the name.

Answer (score 3):

Try `ToLower()` to all:

```
if (s.ToLower().Contains(text.ToLower()))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the string method `ToLower()` if you want all letter lower  or `ToUpper()` if you want all letter Upper

Ex:

```
if(txt!=null)
{
    string text=txt.Text.ToLower();
    foreach(string s in apple)
       if(s.ToLOwer().Equals("YourString")
           lst.Items.Add(s);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the `String.Contains` method does not have an overload that takes a `StringComparison` argument to allow case-insensitive comparisons. However, you can use the [`String.IndexOf`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms224425%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method instead.

```
if (s.IndexOf(text, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [String.IndexOf](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.indexof.aspx) which gives you overload for StringComparison instead -

```
if(s.IndexOf(text, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) != -1)
{

}
```

Add this as an **extension method** to your project which i feel should already be there -

```
public static class StringExtensions
{
    public static bool Contains(this string value, string valueToCheck, 
                                StringComparison comparisonType)
    {
        return value.IndexOf(valueToCheck, comparisonType) != -1;
    }
}
```

Now you can use it like this from your method -

```
if (s.Contains(text, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
```